# Basic laravel Route filter parameters error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I just start learning Laravel today and was reading documentation and testing example codes etc.

I come up with a basic Route Filter Parameters problem which I'm not sure how it works.

From an example on this documentation page http://laravel.com/docs/routing#basic-routing

**The code below could be wrong, I am very new to laravel and not sure yet how it really work**

I got code written as which give me **ERROR**

```
Route::filter('old', function($age)  // a guess is that the correct way to pass $age=400 ?
{
   if($age < 200){
     return Redirect::to(''); 
   }
});

Route::get('user', array('before' => 'old:400', function()
{
    return 'You are over 200 years old!';
}));
```

From this codes its mean that its passing a value of "400" to the filter old right? ... But I don't know how to get that 400 value in the filter... I mean in which variable that "400" is being passed as or how to retrieve that "400" value in filter function.

So the question is how to write that filter function to get that "400" value ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass a parameter or value to be evaluated by the filter you must do it like this:

```
Route::filter('age', function($route, $request, $value)
{
  if($value < 200)
  return Redirect::to('/');
});

Route::get('test', array('before' => 'age:199', function()
{
  return 'Hello World';
}));
```

I followed the same example in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#basic-routing) and it worked.